# Timber loading http version of jQuery causing mixed content issues?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, timber, mixed-content

I have no experience with Timber. Our client just recently handed her site over to us that was previously built by another agency. But the problem is that it is showing a mixed content error on the site that has to do with the jQuery file it is trying to load. It is loading in http instead of https.

I've tried search and replace, but it didn't change the "http" to "https" in this file. I don't know what file is loading it. Normally it would be functions.php in a theme, but I can't find it in there probably due to Timber that uses the Twig templates.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

If we find the file that this script is loading from and change it to https, then the problem will be fixed, but I can't seem to find the file it is located in.

Comment: If you can't find it in the source code, have a look for a plugin which might want to load a newer version of jQuery or simply turn all plugins except Timber off and you will see. Normally, WP is shipped with a lower version of jQuery than this one.

Comment: I don't think any of the other plugins are loading it. I tried disabling all of them (except for Timber) and it was still loading the above script. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: And did you tried to search in code (I would search in theme & plugin folders) for the library, maybe using just part of it, such as `ajax.googleapis.com` ?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help I did end up doing a search with a plugin for searching site files and I managed to find the culprit! =)